# Как использовать дискретную видеокарту в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, администрирование

Собственно вопрос в заголовке, и желательно варианты нужны без установки Bumblebee
Моя версия ubuntu 16.04.2

Comment: Что за видеокарта, как вы хотите её использовать и какие проблемы с использованием сейчас?

Comment: Видеокарта Nvidia geforce 940mx, хочу использовать ее при запуске игр, и помойму я понял что мою карту комп даже не распознает хотя на виндовс все нормально(...

Comment: Окей, а при чём тут сервер и администрирование?

Comment: sudo apt-get install nvidia-current